# Regular expression to validate valid time

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regular expression to validate time.

Valid values would be from `0:00` to `23:59`.

When the time is less than `10:00` it should also support one character numbers.

These are valid values:

- `9:00`
- `09:00`

Comment: Sorry I mistyped, I'd like the first number to support 1 character. ie: 2:00 AND 02:00

Comment: Are `00:00`, `01:00`, … valid values?

Comment: Is there a reason you want only regular expression answers?

Comment: It's for use in a RegularExpressionValidator

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
^(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Or to be more distinct:

```
^(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't want to steal anyone's hard work but [this](http://alperguc.blogspot.com/2008/11/c-regex-time-validation-with-regular.html) is exactly what you're looking for, apparently.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public bool IsValidTime(string thetime)
{
    Regex checktime =
        new Regex(@"^(20|21|22|23|[01]d|d)(([:][0-5]d){1,2})$");

    return checktime.IsMatch(thetime);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this has gotten upvotes when it doesn't work.  Those three `d` characters will only match the literal character `d`, so this returns `false` for `"00:00"` and `"23:59"` but returns `true` for `"0d:0d"`.  They should instead be [``\d``](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#decimal-digit-character-d) or `[0-9]` to match any decimal digit.  The next line of that blog entry, which is absent from this answer, is "**Time regular expression** used to control time is `^(20|21|22|23|[01]\d|\d)(([:][0-5]\d){1,2})$`".

Answer (score 8):

I'd just use DateTime.TryParse().

```
DateTime time;
string timeStr = "23:00"

if(DateTime.TryParse(timeStr, out time))
{
  /* use time or timeStr for your bidding */
}
```

Comment: It's for Client-Side validation

Answer (score 2):

The regex `^(2[0-3]|[01]d)([:][0-5]d)$` should match 00:00 to 23:59. Don't know C# and hence can't give you the relevant code.

/RS

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow **military** and **standard** with the use of **AM and PM** (optional and insensitive), then you may want to give this a try.

```
^(?:(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]\s?(?:[AP][Mm]?|[ap][m]?)?|(?:00?|1[3-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$
```

Answer (score 2):

Very late to the party but I created this Regex which I found work the best for 24H format (HH:mm:ss OR HH:mm OR H:mm:ss OR H:mm):

```cs
private bool TimePatternValidation(string time)
    => new Regex(@"^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3]))(:([0-5][0-9])){1,2}$").IsMatch(time);
```

Comment: As you noted, this matches the `HH:mm:ss` format, which was not requested by the question, yet fails to match the `H:mm` format, which _was_ requested by the question.

Comment: You right, i fixed it.
Now it work on every time pattern (HH:mm:ss | H:mm:ss | HH:mm | H:mm)

Answer (score 1):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)$", 
                   ErrorMessage = "Invalid Time.")]
```

Try this

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Better!!!

```
    public bool esvalida_la_hora(string thetime)
    {
        Regex checktime = new Regex("^(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$");
        if (!checktime.IsMatch(thetime))
            return false;

        if (thetime.Trim().Length < 5)
            thetime = thetime = "0" + thetime;

        string hh = thetime.Substring(0, 2);
        string mm = thetime.Substring(3, 2);

        int hh_i, mm_i;
        if ((int.TryParse(hh, out hh_i)) && (int.TryParse(mm, out mm_i)))
        {
            if ((hh_i >= 0 && hh_i <= 23) && (mm_i >= 0 && mm_i <= 59))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Why is this better? It appears this answer doesn't meet the criteria of the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool IsTimeString(string ts)
{
    if (ts.Length == 5 && ts.Contains(':'))
    {
        int h;
        int m;
        return int.TryParse(ts.Substring(0, 2), out h) 
                            && int.TryParse(ts.Substring(3, 2), out m) 
                            && h >= 0 && h < 24 
                            && m >= 0 && m < 60;
     }
     else
         return false;
}
```

Comment: Add more details in you answer.