# CustomValidator time c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, validation

I have using c#.net.

I have a textbox which should contain a time. It needs to be in 24 hour format.

I would like to use a CustomValidator but can’t find anything on the net.

Thanks in advance for any help

Clare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using CustomValidator check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28VS.80%29.aspx), but I prefer [regular expression validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) instead.

Check this question about validation of time with Regular Expression Validator :

[Regular expression to validate valid time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884848/regular-expression-to-validate-valid-time)

Comment: I have added the RegularExpressionValidator (RegEx taken from the other post). However even though the time is incorrect it still allows me to update (update button) do I need to do client side validation?

Comment: If you would like to block the user from saving the form after inputting an incorrect time then you'll need at least server side validation- and client-side validation isn't a bad idea either. Can you post your code in the original question?

Answer (score 1):

Use this "([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]" regular expression in regular expression validator