# python simple regex help

Tags: python, regex

Hi first time regex user here.
Just trying to figure out some regex but need some help.

I have a text file with the following items:

10:67 12:12 01:50 23:60 23:50

And I'm trying to get a list of the valid times so the 
output should be:

['12:12', '01:50', '23:50']

Here is my code:

```
import re
inFile = open("text.txt")
text = inFile.read()
pattern = re.findall('([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d', text)
print pattern
```

My output is:

['12', '01', '23']

Any help figuring out whats wrong? Thanks!!!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884848/regular-expression-to-validate-valid-time for a good regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python apparently only prints the first group (that's `([01]\d|2[0-3])` in your case). If you make a non-capturing group (`(?: ... )`) of it, you should see the desired result:

```
text = '10:67 12:12 01:50 23:60 23:50'
pattern = re.findall('(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d', text)
print pattern
```

displays:

```
['12:12', '01:50', '23:50']
```

More info on (non-) capturing groups: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Actually, ``findall()`` returns all groups or, if there are no groups, the entire match (to see this, add a second group around the minutes to the original expression and Python will return a tuple). Making the group non-capturing is the correct answer though.

Comment: @Blair, I was already looking for an explanation in the Python docs to find out the exact behavior. Thanks!