# Python regex issue

Tags: python, xml, regex, wurfl

I'm trying to extract ALL phone screen resolutions from the WURFL XML file with the below Python script. The problem is that I only get the first match, though. Why? How could I get all matches?

The WURFL XML file can be found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/wurfl/files/WURFL/latest/wurfl-latest.zip/download?use_mirror=freefr

```
def read_file(file_name):
    f = open(file_name, 'rb')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    return data

text = read_file('wurfl.xml')

import re
pattern = '<device id="(.*?)".*actual_device_root="true">.*<capability name="resolution_width" value="(\d+)"/>.*<capability name="resolution_height" value="(\d+)"/>.*</device>'
for m in re.findall(pattern, text, re.DOTALL):
    print(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use an XML parser instead of regular expressions. You'll be happier in the long run.

Second, if you insist on using regexes, use `finditer()` instead of `findall()`.

Third, your regex matches from the first entry to the last one (the `.*` is greedy, and you have set `DOTALL` mode), so either see the first paragraph or at least change your regex to

```
pattern = r'<device id="(.*?)".*?actual_device_root="true">.*?<capability name="resolution_width" value="(\d+)"/>.*?<capability name="resolution_height" value="(\d+)"/>.*?</device>'
```

Also, always use raw strings with regexes. `\d` happens to work, `\b` will behave unexpectedly in a "normal" string, though.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I still only get one match

Comment: Oops, I overlooked one greedy quantifier. Please try again with the edited regex.

Answer (score 0):

This is an oddness in the behaviour of `findall`, specifically `findall` only returns the first matching group from each pattern match. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946905/python-simple-regex-help).

Comment: Clarification: I get the groups I'm interested in but findall only returns ONE match (the first match) for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "greedy" matches: `.*` will match as much text as it can grab, which means the `.*` before `<capabilities>` matches most of the file.

```
text = open('wurfl.xml').read()
pattern = r'<device id="(.*?)".*?actual_device_root="true">.*?<capability name="resolution_width" value="(\d+)"/>.*?<capability name="resolution_height" value="(\d+)"/>.*?</device>'
for m in re.findall(pattern, text, re.DOTALL):
    print m
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly not averse to handling xml with a regexp if the requirements are simple, but perhaps in this case using a real xml parser would be better. Using the stdlib etree module and a sprinkling of (imho) hideous xpaths:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def capability_value(cap_elem):
    if cap_elem is None:
        return None
    return int(cap_elem.attrib.get('value'))

def devices(wurfl_doc):
    for el in wurfl_doc.findall("/devices/device[@actual_device_root='true']"):
        width = el.find("./group[@id='display']/capability[@name='resolution_width']")
        width = capability_value(width)
        height = el.find("./group[@id='display']/capability[@name='resolution_height']")
        height = capability_value(height)
        device = {
            'id' : el.attrib.get('id'), 
            'resolution' : {'width': width, 'height': height}
        }
        yield device

doc = ET.ElementTree(file='wurfl.xml')
for device in devices(doc):
    print device
```