# regex for validating time in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to validate valid time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884848/regular-expression-to-validate-valid-time)

i wrote this code for validating time in asp.net
*

what are the errors if i use "[0-9]?[0-9]+:[0-9]+[0-9]+:[0-9]+[0-9]+" for hh:mm:ss format.Will it work for all cases?

Comment: It will not work in all cases, you are missing culture information. If you know that the date/time is always in the same culture it will work.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [TimeSpan.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd987680.aspx) rather than regex to parse a string and see if you get `true` or `false`

```
TimeSpan tempTimeSpan;
if (TimeSpan.TryParse("12:22:33", out tempTimeSpan))
{
    //valid time
}
else
{
    //Invalid time
}
```

Comment: the user enters the value in textbox i am trying to validate it using regular expression

Comment: Why regular expression ? If the format is different, then you may use [`TimeSpan.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784009.aspx) with the format.

Comment: It will not work in all cases, you are missing culture information. If you know that the date/time is always in the same culture it will work

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet of regex could be of help for validating dates with time. This takes care of leap year also.

```
^(?=\d)(?:(?:31(?!.(?:0?[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?!.0?2)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))([-./])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$
```